# How to calculating the UV Index

Tags: weather-api, openweathermap

Can I calculating UV index from this infos?

```
"precipIntensity": 0.0028,
"precipProbability": 0.08,
"precipType": "rain",
"temperature": 96.72,
"apparentTemperature": 112.71,
"dewPoint": 77.22,
"humidity": 0.54,
"windSpeed": 1.7,
"windBearing": 173,
"visibility": 6.21,
"cloudCover": 0.43,
"pressure": 1001.25,
"ozone": 275.78
```

I use forecast.io api to make an application, but I can't found uv index values! Can I calculating UV index from this infos?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Look at that document with UV Index calculation explanations based on current weather and geo data: [Calculation of UVI for Smartphone Apps](https://uv2go.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/calculation-of-uvi-for-smartphone-apps3.pdf).

You could also check [OpenUV - Global UV Index Forecast API](https://www.openuv.io).